# install chromedriver extension, not full directory?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

install chromedriver extension, not full directory ?

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument(--load-extension=../extension')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=800,980")
        chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
```

not

**chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension=full path directory/extension')**

install webdriver extension, not full directory ?

Answer (score 0):

On [the ChromeDriver site](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/extensions), only the **full path** is mentioned. This seems reasonable to me, as a relative path could be difficult to interpret: Is it relativ to the `chrome.exe` dir? To the `chromedriver` dir? To the CWD?

Anyway, a web search found some examples using a relative path as well, so both seems possible. If in doubt, you can just convert your relative path to an absolute one using

```py
import os
absolutePath = os.path.abspath(relativePath)
```